# How to resize a squares to fit inside a screen using Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity3d. Is it easy to write a program who scale and distribute squares after the size of the screen. It would have been cool to have it in 3D, but 2D is also working for my case. The animated Gif, show what I want. Hope someone can help me with an example of how this can be done. Tanks!

To calculte the square size I use the following function:

```c#
        public static double getPieceSquareCalculated(int height, int width, int numberOfPieces)
    {
        double px = Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(numberOfPieces * width / height)) +1;
        px = px == 0 ? 1 : px; 
        double sx, sy;
        if (Math.Floor(px * height / width) * px < numberOfPieces)  
            sx = height / Math.Ceiling(px * height / width);
        else
            sx = width / px;
        double py = Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(numberOfPieces * height / width))+1;
        py = py == 0 ? 1 : py; 
        if (Math.Floor(py * width / height) * py < numberOfPieces)  
            sy = width / Math.Ceiling(width * py / height);
        else
            sy = height / py;
        return Math.Max(sx, sy);
    }
```

[image: Scale squares after resize screen]

Comment: Do you need it for UI?

Comment: I would use it in my game.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity 5 ui. Then, hopefully following script will help.
Here's a GIF of what it does:
[image]
You can attach it to a Panel and it's children will change layout and size dynamically. It is actually a variation of Unity's Grid Layout Group:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// AutoExpandGridLayoutGroup a variation of Unity's Grid Layout Group.
/// It sorts children under a panel into dynamic grid layout. 
/// Also resizes children inside panel according to panel size and child count. 
/// Helps taken from https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-how-to-make-grid-layout-group-cell-size-x-auto-expand.448534/
/// </summary>
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnityEngine.UI
{
    [AddComponentMenu("Layout/Auto Expand Grid Layout Group", 152)]
    public class AutoExpandGridLayoutGroup : LayoutGroup
    {
        public enum Corner { UpperLeft = 0, UpperRight = 1, LowerLeft = 2, LowerRight = 3 }
        public enum Axis { Horizontal = 0, Vertical = 1 }
        public enum Constraint { Flexible = 0, FixedColumnCount = 1, FixedRowCount = 2 }

        [SerializeField]
        protected Corner m_StartCorner = Corner.UpperLeft;
        public Corner startCorner { get { return m_StartCorner; } set { SetProperty(ref m_StartCorner, value); } }

        [SerializeField]
        protected Axis m_StartAxis = Axis.Horizontal;
        public Axis startAxis { get { return m_StartAxis; } set { SetProperty(ref m_StartAxis, value); } }

        [SerializeField]
        protected Vector2 m_CellSize = new Vector2(100, 100);
        public Vector2 cellSize { get { return m_CellSize; } set { SetProperty(ref m_CellSize, value); } }

        [SerializeField]
        protected Vector2 m_Spacing = Vector2.zero;
        public Vector2 spacing { get { return m_Spacing; } set { SetProperty(ref m_Spacing, value); } }

        [SerializeField]
        protected Constraint m_Constraint = Constraint.Flexible;
        public Constraint constraint { get { return m_Constraint; } set { SetProperty(ref m_Constraint, value); } }

        [SerializeField]
        protected int m_ConstraintCount = 2;
        public int constraintCount { get { return m_ConstraintCount; } set { SetProperty(ref m_ConstraintCount, Mathf.Max(1, value)); } }

        protected AutoExpandGridLayoutGroup()
        { }

        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        protected override void OnValidate()
        {
            base.OnValidate();
            constraintCount = constraintCount;
        }
        #endif

        protected override void OnRectTransformDimensionsChange(){
            base.OnRectTransformDimensionsChange ();
            float meSize = getPieceSquareCalculated (rectTransform.rect.size.y, rectTransform.rect.size.x, rectChildren.Count);
            m_CellSize = new Vector2 (meSize,meSize);
        }
        protected virtual void OnTransformChildrenChanged(){
            base.OnTransformChildrenChanged();
            float meSize = getPieceSquareCalculated (rectTransform.rect.size.y, rectTransform.rect.size.x, rectChildren.Count);
            m_CellSize = new Vector2 (meSize,meSize);
        }
        public override void CalculateLayoutInputHorizontal()
        {
            base.CalculateLayoutInputHorizontal();

            int minColumns = 0;
            int preferredColumns = 0;
            if (m_Constraint == Constraint.FixedColumnCount)
            {
                minColumns = preferredColumns = m_ConstraintCount;
            }
            else if (m_Constraint == Constraint.FixedRowCount)
            {
                minColumns = preferredColumns = Mathf.CeilToInt(rectChildren.Count / (float)m_ConstraintCount - 0.001f);
            }
            else
            {
                minColumns = 1;
                preferredColumns = Mathf.CeilToInt(Mathf.Sqrt(rectChildren.Count));
            }

            SetLayoutInputForAxis(
                padding.horizontal + (cellSize.x + spacing.x) * minColumns - spacing.x,
                padding.horizontal + (cellSize.x + spacing.x) * preferredColumns - spacing.x,
                -1, 0);
        }

        public override void CalculateLayoutInputVertical()
        {
            int minRows = 0;
            if (m_Constraint == Constraint.FixedColumnCount)
            {
                minRows = Mathf.CeilToInt(rectChildren.Count / (float)m_ConstraintCount - 0.001f);
            }
            else if (m_Constraint == Constraint.FixedRowCount)
            {
                minRows = m_ConstraintCount;
            }
            else
            {
                float width = rectTransform.rect.size.x;
                int cellCountX = Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.FloorToInt((width - padding.horizontal + spacing.x + 0.001f) / (cellSize.x + spacing.x)));
                minRows = Mathf.CeilToInt(rectChildren.Count / (float)cellCountX);
            }

            float minSpace = padding.vertical + (cellSize.y + spacing.y) * minRows - spacing.y;
            SetLayoutInputForAxis(minSpace, minSpace, -1, 1);
        }

        public override void SetLayoutHorizontal()
        {
            SetCellsAlongAxis(0);
        }

        public override void SetLayoutVertical()
        {
            SetCellsAlongAxis(1);
        }

        private void SetCellsAlongAxis(int axis)
        {
            // Normally a Layout Controller should only set horizontal values when invoked for the horizontal axis
            // and only vertical values when invoked for the vertical axis.
            // However, in this case we set both the horizontal and vertical position when invoked for the vertical axis.
            // Since we only set the horizontal position and not the size, it shouldn't affect children's layout,
            // and thus shouldn't break the rule that all horizontal layout must be calculated before all vertical layout.

            if (axis == 0)
            {
                // Only set the sizes when invoked for horizontal axis, not the positions.
                for (int i = 0; i < rectChildren.Count; i++)
                {
                    RectTransform rect = rectChildren[i];

                    m_Tracker.Add(this, rect,
                        DrivenTransformProperties.Anchors |
                        DrivenTransformProperties.AnchoredPosition |
                        DrivenTransformProperties.SizeDelta);

                    rect.anchorMin = Vector2.up;
                    rect.anchorMax = Vector2.up;
                    rect.sizeDelta = cellSize;
                }
                return;
            }

            float width = rectTransform.rect.size.x;
            float height = rectTransform.rect.size.y;

            int cellCountX = 1;
            int cellCountY = 1;
            if (m_Constraint == Constraint.FixedColumnCount)
            {
                cellCountX = m_ConstraintCount;
                cellCountY = Mathf.CeilToInt(rectChildren.Count / (float)cellCountX - 0.001f);
            }
            else if (m_Constraint == Constraint.FixedRowCount)
            {
                cellCountY = m_ConstraintCount;
                cellCountX = Mathf.CeilToInt(rectChildren.Count / (float)cellCountY - 0.001f);
            }
            else
            {
                if (cellSize.x + spacing.x <= 0)
                    cellCountX = int.MaxValue;
                else
                    cellCountX = Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.FloorToInt((width - padding.horizontal + spacing.x + 0.001f) / (cellSize.x + spacing.x)));

                if (cellSize.y + spacing.y <= 0)
                    cellCountY = int.MaxValue;
                else
                    cellCountY = Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.FloorToInt((height - padding.vertical + spacing.y + 0.001f) / (cellSize.y + spacing.y)));
            }

            int cornerX = (int)startCorner % 2;
            int cornerY = (int)startCorner / 2;

            int cellsPerMainAxis, actualCellCountX, actualCellCountY;
            if (startAxis == Axis.Horizontal)
            {
                cellsPerMainAxis = cellCountX;
                actualCellCountX = Mathf.Clamp(cellCountX, 1, rectChildren.Count);
                actualCellCountY = Mathf.Clamp(cellCountY, 1, Mathf.CeilToInt(rectChildren.Count / (float)cellsPerMainAxis));
            }
            else
            {
                cellsPerMainAxis = cellCountY;
                actualCellCountY = Mathf.Clamp(cellCountY, 1, rectChildren.Count);
                actualCellCountX = Mathf.Clamp(cellCountX, 1, Mathf.CeilToInt(rectChildren.Count / (float)cellsPerMainAxis));
            }

            Vector2 requiredSpace = new Vector2(
                actualCellCountX * cellSize.x + (actualCellCountX - 1) * spacing.x,
                actualCellCountY * cellSize.y + (actualCellCountY - 1) * spacing.y
            );
            Vector2 startOffset = new Vector2(
                GetStartOffset(0, requiredSpace.x),
                GetStartOffset(1, requiredSpace.y)
            );

            for (int i = 0; i < rectChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                int positionX;
                int positionY;
                if (startAxis == Axis.Horizontal)
                {
                    positionX = i % cellsPerMainAxis;
                    positionY = i / cellsPerMainAxis;
                }
                else
                {
                    positionX = i / cellsPerMainAxis;
                    positionY = i % cellsPerMainAxis;
                }

                if (cornerX == 1)
                    positionX = actualCellCountX - 1 - positionX;
                if (cornerY == 1)
                    positionY = actualCellCountY - 1 - positionY;

                float realsize = ((width - (spacing[0] * (actualCellCountX - 1))) / actualCellCountX);
                SetChildAlongAxis(rectChildren[i], 0, startOffset.x + (realsize + spacing[0]) * positionX, realsize);
                SetChildAlongAxis(rectChildren[i], 1, startOffset.y + (cellSize[1] + spacing[1]) * positionY, cellSize[1]);
            }
        }
        public static float getPieceSquareCalculated(float height, float width, int numberOfPieces)
        {
            float px = Mathf.Ceil(Mathf.Sqrt(numberOfPieces * width / height)) +1;
            px = px == 0 ? 1 : px; 
            float sx, sy;
            if (Mathf.Floor(px * height / width) * px < numberOfPieces)  
                sx = height / Mathf.Ceil(px * height / width);
            else
                sx = width / px;
            float py = Mathf.Ceil(Mathf.Sqrt(numberOfPieces * height / width))+1;
            py = py == 0 ? 1 : py; 
            if (Mathf.Floor(py * width / height) * py < numberOfPieces)  
                sy = width / Mathf.Ceil(width * py / height);
            else
                sy = height / py;
            return Mathf.Max(sx, sy);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will give it a try!. Thanks again!